# I need to merge objects. They all have the same keys but differing numerical values. I need to get the sum of values for each key

Tags: javascript, object

New to JS and programming in general. I've tried numerous solutions on SO and other resources and cannot seem to figure this out. I have twenty or more objects representing user 'votes'. The all have the same keys and different values depending on the user input. I need to 'tally the votes' by summing the different values and return a single object.

Example:

```
{
  "Seattle" : "1",
  "Chicago" : "2",
  "New York" : "3"
}

{
  "Chicago" : "1",
  "New York" : "2",
  "Seattle" : "3"
}

{
  "New York" : "1",
  "Chicago" : "2",
  "Seattle" : "3"
}
```

I'd like the three objects above to be distilled to this:

```
{
  "New York" : "6",
  "Seattle" : "7",
  "Chicago" : "5"
}
```

If you could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are your objects in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your votes are in an array, you can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it into a single object:

```js
const votes = [
  {
    "Seattle" : "1",
    "Chicago" : "2",
    "New York" : "3"
  },
  {
    "Chicago" : "1",
    "New York" : "2",
    "Seattle" : "3"
  },
  {
    "New York" : "1",
    "Chicago" : "2",
    "Seattle" : "3"
  }
];

const tally = votes.reduce((a, e) => {
  for (const p in e) {
    a[p] = a[p] + (+e[p]) || +e[p];
  }
  
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(tally);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `reduce/keys/map` which somewhat more `functional` looking:

```js
const objs = [{
    "Seattle": "1",
    "Chicago": "2",
    "New York": "3"
  },
  {
    "Chicago": "1",
    "New York": "2",
    "Seattle": "3"
  },
  {
    "New York": "1",
    "Chicago": "2",
    "Seattle": "3"
  }
]


var result = objs.reduce((r, c) => Object.keys(r).map((x) => r[x] = +r[x] + (+c[x])) && r)

console.log(result)
```